# Radio input results in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the value selected in a radio to be used as the background colour for my results page.

HTML code:

```
<form action="PhotoForm.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="radio" name="Colour" value="Pink"/> Pink
    <input type="radio" name="Colour" value="Blue"/> Blue
    <input type="radio" name="Colour" value="Green"/> Green
    <input type="radio" name="Colour" value="Grey"/> Grey
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$Color = "white";
$Selection = $_POST["Colour"];
if($Selection == "Pink"){
    $Color = "pink";
}elseif($Selection == "Blue"){
    $Color = "blue";
}elseif($Selection == "Green"){
    $Color = "green";
}elseif($Selection == "Grey"){
    $Color = "SlateGrey";
}
```

I am currently getting the error displayed as:

Notice: Undefined index: Colour in (php file directory) on line 4

I am having issues figuring out why it is displaying this error.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving this notice when submitting the form after having selected one of the radio options, or are you submitting the form without first making a selection?

Comment: Select a radio before.

Comment: You'll probably have to include all of your `PhotoForm.php` code.  There just isn't enough here to go off of.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" is only used when uploading file, leave that part out and it should work

Comment: @XIU The encoding type is not the issue.  The form values will be transmitted just fine using "multipart/form-data".  Also, since this is presumably some kind of photo editing script, the poster is likely submitting a file.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I restarted the computer and it worked fine afterwards. No clue why that would fix it but it did.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
<?php

// key is a color the user may submit, value is the color useful to this program
$validColors = array(
    "pink" => "pink",
    "blue" => "blue",
    "green" => "green",
    "grey" => "SlateGrey",
);

// form has been posted
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') {
    // have an acceptable color
    if (isset($_POST['Colour']) && isset($validColors[strtolower($_POST['Colour'])]) {
        $color = $validColors[strtolower($_POST['Colour'])];
    }
    // no valid color provided
    else {
    }
}
```